# Apply jquery selectbox style on chained selectbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, coding-style, chained

I have created a pair of chained selectboxes in my page. The second selectbox is filled with a set of values, depending on the first box's selected value.

The script that makes the two selectboxes work like this, uses PHP and JavaScript. This is the code I'm using:

**form**

```
<select name="continent" tabindex="1" onChange="getCountry(this.value)">    
  <option value="#">-Select-</option>
  <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
</select>

<div id="countrydiv">
    <select name="country" tabindex="2">
        <option></option>
    </select> 
</div>

<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

**javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="continent"]').selectbox({debug: true});
    $('select[name="country"]').selectbox({debug: true});
});

function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }   
        return xmlhttp;
    }

function getCountry(continentId) {          
    var strURL="findCountry.php?continent="+continentId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('countrydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}
```

**php code (findCountry.php)**

```
<? 
$continent=intval($_GET['continent']);
if ($_GET['continent'] == 'Europe') {
?>
<select name="country">
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
</select>
<? } 
if ($_GET['continent'] == 'Asia') {
?>
<select name="country">
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
</select>
<? } ?>
```

What I want to do is to apply jQuery selectbox styling on these selectboxes. I haven't succeeded in doing that yet. The problem is that jQuery is hiding the normal selectbox and is replacing it with a list. Furthermore, after selectbox's content is refreshed, jquery cannot re-construct it into a list. You can take a look of the jQuery code **[here](http://www.brainfault.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-selectbox-replacement/)**

Is there something I can do to combine these techniques? I have tried a million things but nothing worked. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of your ajax call you need to reassign the selectbox() call. The problem you are experiencing is that DOM elements you setup on page load are gone by the end of your ajax call, replaced with a new select box. If you use the $.ajax or $.get methods in jQuery they give you the option of a completion callback. I would use that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="continent"]').change(function(){
         var continentId = this.value;
         $('select[name="country"]').parent().remove();
         $.ajax({url:"findCountry.php?continent="+continentId,success: function(data){ y = $('<select name="country"><select>');z=$('<div id="countrydiv"></div>'); $('input[type="submit"]').before(z.append(y.append(data))); $('select[name="country"]').selectbox(); }});
    })
})
```

Edit: This works.

Comment: gabriel, thank you very much for you answer. Could you provide some kind of sample code abou the solution you suggest?

Comment: it works! Thank you so much. I'm not a javascript/ajax expert and this issue was beyond my knowledge. Thank's a lot

Answer (score 1):

you are using jQuery, **right?!**

So, lets do this jQuery way....

**form**

```
<select name="continent" tabindex="1" >    
  <option value="#">-Select-</option>
  <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
</select>

<div id="countrydiv">
    <select name="country" tabindex="2">
        <option></option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="continent"]').change(function(){
         var continentId = this.value;
         $('select[name="country"]').load("findCountry.php?continent="+continentId)
    })
})
```

**php code (findCountry.php)**

```
<? 
$continent=intval($_GET['continent']);
if ($_GET['continent'] == 'Europe') {
?>    
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>

<? } 
if ($_GET['continent'] == 'Asia') {
?>    
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>

<? } ?>
```

Comment: Reigel, thank you very much for answer. Your code works almost ok as the jquery styling part is not working. In order to apply style to these selectboxes, I have to add some extra code "$('select[name="continent"]').selectbox({debug: true});". But adding this code makes the form not working properly again and takes us back to the problem of combining these techniques together.

Comment: I uploaded the page here: http://idealklima.gr/test_selectbox.php.
You can test it better this way. I have applied the changes you suggested in your answer

Comment: am I doing something wrong here? can you help me fix it please?

Comment: the problem is the structure of the plugin you are using... it can be done,but hard way...